# Finding upper bound

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, python

Since upper bound refers to finding the maximum amount of time (in Big-oh) the function would take, would it be save to assume that I have to find the maximum amount of time when b > n? I'm saying this because than the inner loop would have to run the maximum number of times right?

Am i on the right track? Anything else I should consider?

```
def someloop(n):

"""Assume n is an integer and n > 1."""

    b = 1

    while b <= n:
        i = 1
        while i < b:
            print(i)
            i = i*3
        b = b + 1
```

Comment: Is the identation correct  now?

Comment: Uhh, same. I know the indentation is messed, but I don't think it should be that much of an issue...

Comment: @toliveira Now it's correct. Thanks.

Comment: The upper bound should be a function of $n$. So for every n, you can count how many times the code in the nested loop will be executed.